# How to setup babel-cli to run react-native ES6 JavaScript code on command line?

Tags: node.js, react-native, ecmascript-6, babel-cli

My goal is to run ES6 JavaScript code containing console.log statements on the command line to help debug code before integrating with my React Native app.  This code contains only JS functions.

This is what I tried:

```
Install babel-cli
   npm install --save-dev babel-cli

File: .babelrc ( in project root )
{
  "presets": ["react-native"]
}

Run sandbox:
./node_modules/.bin/babel-node app/components/sandbox.js
```

I get the following run-time error:

```
   /react-native/myapp/source/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native.js:15
    if (__DEV__) {
        ^
        ReferenceError: __DEV__ is not defined
```

I had this working once.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Native is a different environment than Node, not just transpiled code. You cannot run React Native apps directly on Node like you cannot run web pages on Node.

When testing, you can use the mocking feature of [jest](http://facebook.github.io/jest/) to mock React Native specific modules. The `react-native` preset for jest already does that.

Comment: I want to run a JS module that contains only JS functions on the command line. No JSX, and no react native imports.  I had this working once.  Now I get a run-time error "__DEV__ is not defined"

Comment: From the error message it looks like you have a import for React Native. Though it's hard to say anything without looking at your code.

Comment: Thanks satya164.  You are right, once I removed an import of a file that imported a react native import the JS code would run.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I should try to learn to use jest next time I have a bunch of new JS code to test and debug.